# Redirecting to different angular applications from Parent app deployed on blob storage

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-ad-b2c

We have 3-4 different applications hosted on dedicated blob storage using same ADB2C tenant as an identity provider.

https://abc.z33.web.core.windows.net/

https://def.z33.web.core.windows.net/

https://xyz.z33.web.core.windows.net/

So as soon as the user hits the URL it is redirected to the signin page configured in b2c.

Now we have a requirement to build a unified login. i.e open a common dashboard page where respective applications will be displayed for which user has an access and they can be navigated to respective above mentioned Url's once they clicked it.

The challenge we are facing is managing single session for all the URL's. If I try to login to an application independently and then hit the different URL in same session it again asks me to login. As we are using same tenant shouldn't it be redirected to the landing screen rather than login?

Also is there a way to deploy sub folders as an application inside azure blob storage so that I have a below structure

ParentApp - Dashboard Screen presenting all the application user have access to
Child1 - Subfolder containing Application1
Child2 - Subfolder containing Application2

Or if there is any other efficient way in Angular to redirect to different application maintaining the ADb2C session?